# SQL: Use where to search current query with parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, parameters, where-clause

This is what I´m thinking:

```
DECLARE @Search varchar(150)
SET @Search = 'CompanyName'

SELECT a, b, c, d, e
FROM Table
WHERE a, b, c, d, e in (@Search)
```

Is this possible? And if so, can the where condition be set to:

```
WHERE a, b, c, d, e in (('%')+(@Search))
```

So that it will search for all connections according to the search??

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to select rows where `a, b, c, d` or `e` contain the string `'Companyname'`?

Comment: Flip it around? `where @search in (a,b,c,d,e)` - you cannot use a wildcard with `in()` you would need to break out into `OR`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work!**

```
DECLARE @Search varchar(150)
SET @Search = 'CompanyName'

SELECT a, b, c, d, e
FROM Table
WHERE a = @Search or 
      b = @Search or 
      c = @Search or 
      d = @Search or 
      e = @Search


 SELECT a, b, c, d, e
    FROM Table
    WHERE a like '%' +  @Search + '%' or 
          b like '%' + @Search + '%' or 
          c like '%' + @Search + '%' or 
          d like '%' + @Search + '%' or 
          e like '%' + @Search + '%'
```

Comment: OK looks good, but I´m getting problems with null data that should not pop up. Using your example and adding: where a is not null etc.